# NFS using different versions of operating systems

Tags: operating-system, nfs

We have an NFS server on which a 32-bit kernel of Debian is installed. I want to run an application which works only if the kernel is 64-bit. We have in all about 60-70 PC's, out of which the above mentioned application is run only on 10 nodes. Is it possible to install a seperate operating system for these 10 nodes without breaking any protocol in NFS ?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1813.txt there is a section on 32/64 bit compatibility issues with version 3 of the NFS protocol (from back in 1995). This is the relevant section for your case with a 32-bit server and 64-bit client, which indicates there should be no problem handling this combination, unlike the issue of 64-bit server and 32-bit client:

> 4.13 32 bit clients/servers and 64 bit clients/servers
>
> The 64 bit nature of the NFS version 3 protocol introduces
>   several compatibility problems. The most notable two are    mismatched
>   clients and servers, that is, a 32 bit client and    a 64 bit server
>   or a 64 bit client and a 32 bit server.
>
> The problems of a 64 bit client and a 32 bit server are easy    to
>   handle. The client will never encounter a file that it can    not
>   handle. If it sends a request to the server that the    server can not
>   handle, the server should reject the request    with an appropriate
>   error.
>
> The problems of a 32 bit client and a 64 bit server are much
>   harder to handle...